# My code is showing this error: ValueError: X has 8 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I removed the read_csv

```
rt pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.base import ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import (
    accuracy_score,
    f1_score,
    confusion_matrix,
    classification_report,
    recall_score,
)
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn import datasets


df = pd.read_csv(
    "/Users/_______/Desktop/Daiabities_1.csv", delimiter=";", decimal=","
)
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 1000)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 1000)
pd.set_option("display.width", 1000)

df.info()
print(df.head(4))
print(df.shape)
print(df.describe())
print(df.corr())

x = df.iloc[:, 0:8]
y = df.iloc[:, -1]
best_features = SelectKBest(score_func=chi2, k=3)
fit = best_features.fit(x, y)
df_scores = pd.DataFrame(fit.scores_)
df_columns = pd.DataFrame(x.columns)
features_scores = pd.concat([df_columns, df_scores], axis=1)
features_scores.columns = ["Features", "Score"]
features_scores.sort_values(by="Score")
print(features_scores)

x = df[["Glucose", "Insulin", "Age"]]
y = df[["Outcome"]]
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    x, y, test_size=0.4, random_state=100
)
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = logreg.predict(x_test)
print(x_test)
print(y_pred)

models = [
    LogisticRegression(),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(),
    RandomForestClassifier(),
    SVC(kernel="poly"),
    MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(128), max_iter=100),
]

for model in models:
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
    print(f"Model {model}")
    print(f"Accuracy score is {accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"F1 score is {f1_score(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"Recall is {recall_score(y_test, y_pred)}")
    print(f"Confusin Matrix\n{confusion_matrix(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print(f"Classification report\n{classification_report(y_test,y_pred)}")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------")


input_data = []

preg = input()
gluc = input()
bloodpr = input()
skinth = input()
insu = input()
bmi = input()
dpf = input()
age = input()

input_data.extend([preg, gluc, bloodpr, skinth, insu, bmi, dpf, age])


data_to_np_array = np.asarray(input_data)
input_data_reshaped = data_to_np_array.reshape(1, -1)
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(x)
std_data = scaler.transform(input_data_reshaped)
print(std_data)
classifier = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")
prediction = classifier.predict(std_data)
print(prediction)

if prediction[0] == 0:
    print("The person is not Diabetic.")
else:
    print("The person is Diabetic.")
```

Tried looking for other responses and tried starting the code again but none of this solved the issue. If somebody coulda dice on this issue it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please post the full error trace and remove unnecessary code that comes after the error - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small script that leads to the same error and I suppose for the same reason

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

a = np.random.random([100, 3])
b = np.random.random([100, 8])

scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(a)
scaler.transform(b)
```

```
ValueError: X has 8 features, but StandardScaler is expecting 3 features as input.
```

So the problem is you fit on data with 3 features and try to apply it to something with 8 features. So check your `x` if it has the correct shape, should also have 8 features then, or if whatever you try to scale should have 8 features.

You can also run

```
print(scaler.n_features_in_)
```

to see on how many features the scaler encountered during the fit.